# How to filter out item from array in object property

Tags: javascript

I have an array of objects with this structure

```
mockData: [{
    'ONE': [{
      id: 11,
      ...
    }, {
      id: 4,
      ...
    }]
  },
  {
    'TWO': [{
      id: 11,
      ...
    }]
  }
]
```

I want to filter out the item by id (for example with id === 11) and by Object key. For exmaple I want to delete

```
'ONE': [{
      id: 11,
      ...
    }
```

but leave the

```
 {
    'TWO': [{
      id: 11,
      ...
    }]
  }
```

I figured out that filter just by id

```
mockData.map(item => {
  return Object.values(item).map(inner => {
    return inner.filter(i => i.id !== id)
  });
})
```

This works but it removes the key of the object ('ONE', 'TWO' etc.) and returns data like this

```
[[{id:3, ...}]],
[[]]
```

instead of

```
'TWO': []
```

All the help with adjusting my function to work properly will be much appreciated.

Also, I'm doing it in Redux reducer, so I can't mutate the initial array.

Comment: you mean keep ONE with id: 4, right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try using the `Array.reduce` method.

Example:

```js
const data = [
  {
    ONE: [{ id: 11 }, { id: 12 }, { id: 13 }],
    TWO: [{ id: 11 }, { id: 12 }, { id: 13 }]
  }
];

const filtered = data.map(item => {
  return Object.keys(item).reduce((prev, key) => {
    prev[key] = item[key].filter(({ id }) => id !== 11);
    return prev;
  }, {});
});
console.log(filtered)
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to separate the parts and get the most inner array along with the key and then add this result to the outer array.

```js
const
    filter = (array, id) => array.reduce((r, o) => {
        var hasContent,
            content = Object.assign({}, ...Object.entries(o).map(([k, v]) => {
                v = v.filter(o => o.id !== id);
                if (v.length) {
                    hasContent = true;
                    return { [k]: v };
                }
            }));
        if (hasContent) r.push(content);
        return r;
    }, []);

var data = { mockData: [{ ONE: [{ id: 11 }, { id: 4 }] }, { TWO: [{ id: 11 }] }] }

console.log(filter(data.mockData, 11));
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```